# CSS Styling Angular 2+ (pain in the butt)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Ok, i am new to Angular 4. I am having issues with styling the application properly. I went ahead and added a `background image` to the body, this worked as expected, then added a component that would display content and it looked as expected.

I added a second component different route but for this one I do not want the body to have the `background image` at this point i am not sure what is the best practice.

I read a few articles and some say that you can have a different `style` for the body at the component level by adding a `body style override` in the `styleUrls`. I did this but everytime i went from say `/myroute/page2` to `myroute/page1` the background sticked to what i set for `myroute/page2` while it should show the body image for `/myroute/page1`. I am also using ViewEncapsulation set to None (maybe this is the issue)?.

Also this is my setup and may be wrong too

index.html has something like this:

```
</head>
 <body>
   <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

then my app.component.html has this:

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and then i have my welcome.component.html that has a section

```
<section id="hero">
  <div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now the component above shows the background set correctly, but if I navigate using something like

```
 this.router.navigate(['/page2']);
```

the background stays the same as in my welcome component. If i refresh on `/page2` the right background now shows up.

**UPDATE:**
Ok i gave up on showing the background on the second component, i wanted without background image, but want to keep the one in the first component. So i removed the ViewEncapsulation from all of them but now if I move the `body {}` to the first component it does not show it for some reason (I made sure it has the right path). Is there a better fix than removing it by using the DOM?. What is the best practice?.

Comment: This is because you have set ViewEncapsulation set to none due to which the body style is always visible. You can dynamically set background via code when your component  loads (ngOnInit) and reset it back when component is destroyed (ngOnDestroy)

Comment: I removed all the ViewEncapsulation, now even if i place body {} in the component css it does not show the background image. I cant believe this is so complicated in Angular 4!!. All i want is to show the background for the body for component A, then all the other ones should remain without it.

Comment: Yes, with default ViewEncapsulation this is the expected behavior that the styles you define for that component will have its scope limited to that component only (I'd say the beauty of Angular). Now what you can do is setting styling within your Component Code.[See my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545958/4632215)

Comment: That worked, i tried putting the class on my component .css file but it does not pick it from there. If i place it on the styles.css on the root it takes it. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set style class on ngOnInit and remove it on ngOnDestroy.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
   }

ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'your_class');
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'your_class');
  }
```

Comment: what is renderer? is that part of @angular/core?

Comment: Why I'm using it because it is recommended for making your app universal. Though you can use Veena answer as it is also correct but it may cause issues in some devices, whereas using Renderer2 gives overhead to angular of applying styles to different devices.

Comment: That worked, i tried putting the class on my component .css file but it does not pick it from there. If i place it on the styles.css on the root it takes it. Why is that?

Comment: This is due to Emulated View Encapsulation of Angular due to which the style scope is limited only to those component/class in which it has been imported.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, pls try. In your component1,

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.body.style.background="url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSu5rIAFQkkswZLuwAUCXZqc_8bBROGkGgmZP5bmGk57sRKXWJMEg)";
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  document.body.style.background="";
}
```

In your component2,

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.body.style.background="url(http://gkreading.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/awesome-kid-in-the-grass.jpg)";
}
ngOnDestroy() {
      document.body.style.background="";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Direct DOM manipulations are not recommended in angular. Try @HostBinding('style.background-image')

Comment: where do i add that?

Comment: @jedgard: can you quickly create a plukr with repro, so that I can help on that. https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: There has to be a better way!. If i create a new component then i have to keep removing the background?!!